# Rails angular coffeescript error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm using angularjs-rails gem.
I've created angular_app folder in assets, and have angular_app/controllers/phoneListController.js.coffee, and angular_app/modules/phoneCatApp.js.coffee (*yeah you're right I'm doing angular's phone tutorial ). So `angular_app/controllers/phoneListController.js.coffee` has:

```
phonecatApp.controller 'PhoneListController', ($scope) ->
  $scope.phones = [
    { 'name': 'Nexus S'
      'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'
    }
    {
      'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi'
      'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
    }
    {
      'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™'
      'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
    }
  ]
  return
```

`angular_app/modules/phoneCatApp.js.coffee` has:

```
phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [])
```

Every thing works fine if I use vanila js in `angular_app/modules/phoneCatApp.js.coffee` using `phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [])`` (with backsticks).

So problem is that coffee covers all in anonymous function with ().call.this. What should I do to make it work in coffee?

Comment: in angular_app/controllers/phoneListController.js.coffee it seems like you are not adding $scope as dependency. this line should be: phonecatApp.controller 'PhoneListController', '$scope',  ($scope) -> ...

Comment: Doesn't work: phonecatApp is not defined

Comment: do you have an index.js.coffee file where you declare the files to be included in your project?

Comment: they're in asset pipeline and served right (I can see them in chrome's dev panel), and everything works if i declare module in pure JS.

Comment: What I do is direct call `angular.module('phonecatApp').controller ...` with assets pipeline directive `require <file  with your module definition>`. Local variables are not passed between coffee files.

Comment: are you sure its not the void return at the end that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as you've stated, is the

```
(function() { ... }).call(this)
```

that the coffeescript compiler generates.  To make `phonecatApp` a global simply do

```
this.phonecatApp = phonecatApp
```

in your `angular_app/modules/phoneCatApp.js.coffee` file after the `angular.module()` call.

However, MUCH better is to use:

```
angular.module('phonecatApp').controller( ... )
```

to define your controllers.  This version gets angular to provide the module singleton on which to define the controller.